# having a count column from a subquery that's querying the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets say i have the table:

**accounts**: id, id2, id3, custId, option1, option2, type

and this same table has ALL accounts with some being "parent" accounts (which can be "solo" accounts with no children) and some being "children" accounts  (bad design i know, but that's what I'm working with).

The distinct/composite key for each account is `id + id2 + id3 + option1 + option2 + custId`.

I want to query a list of "parent" or "solo" accounts with a specific `custId` and `type`, which is easily done by:

```
Select *
From accounts
Where custId = 1 And type = 'foo'
and (option1 = 'solo' Or option2 = 0)
```

where `'solo'` means it's a solo account and has no children and `0` means that's its the first of a line of accounts and therefore its parent.

Then I want to obtain the count of "children" associated to every parent obtained by the result set of the above query. Obviously "solo" accounts won't have children.

For example obtaining the "children" count from a specific "parent" account would be something like (let's say I'm looking for the children of account with id=1, id2=1, id3=1:

```
Select Count(*)
From accounts
Where id = 1 And id2 = 1 And id3 = 1 And custId = 1 
And option1 != 'solo' And option2 != 0)
```

So how can I combine the two queries in order to obtain the result set of the first with counts for each of its rows?

**Example**

populating the table we could have:

```
 id    id2    id3     custId     option1     option2     type
 ------------------------------------------------------------
  1     1      1        1         solo        9           foo
  2     2      2        1         solo        9           foo
  3     4      4        1         NULL        0           foo
  3     4      4        1         NULL        1           foo
  3     4      4        1         NULL        2           foo
```

I want a result set like this:

```
 id    id2    id3     custId     option1     option2     type     children
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1     1      1        1         solo        9           foo      0
  2     2      2        1         solo        9           foo      0 
  3     4      4        1         NULL        0           foo      2
```

Basically I would want something like this (i know this is wrong)

```
Select *, 
(Select count(*) from accounts
Where option1 != 'solo' And option2 != 0
And --all 3 ids and custId equal to the current row
) --this is the part i don't know how to do 
From accounts
Where custId = 1 And Type = 'foo' And (option1 = 'solo' Or option2 = 0)
```

My brain is running circles around how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your data:

```
select a.*
  , children = isnull(c.children, 0)
from accounts a
  outer apply (select children = count(1)
              from accounts c
               where a.option1 is null
                and a.id = c.id
                and a.id2 = c.id2
                and a.id3 = c.id3
                and a.custId = c.custId
                and c.option2 <> 0) c
where (a.option1 = 'solo' or a.option2 = 0)
  and a.type = 'foo'
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0579/2).

**Edit after comment:**

OK, so the main part of the query is the `WHERE` clause - this determines the three rows that are returned.

Once we have these rows, we need to work out how many children there are - this is what the `OUTER APPLY` achieves.

Basically, for each non-solo row, we match this to any child rows (i.e. `c.option2 <> 0`) and get a count of these rows, explicitly returning 0 when there are now matches or it is a **'solo'** parent row.

Since we are only matching against non-solo parent rows, we filter these with `a.option1 is null`, i.e. checking the parent row `option1` values before checking for any matches. Due to the nature of the data, `c.option1 is null` would be fine, too, as both parent and child non-solo rows have `null` `option1` values.

`count(1)` doesn't mean anything in particular; it's just an arbitrary value to be counted for each row, in this case a constant. You could just as easily use `count(*)`. Back in the day this might have made a difference in query processing but with modern RDBMS optimisers you won't see any differences.

Here's an alternate query that does it a slightly different way:

```
select a.*
  , children = isnull(c.children, 0)
from accounts a
  left join (select children = count(*)
               , id
               , id2
               , id3
               , custId
              from accounts
              where option1 is null and option2 <> 0
              group by id
               , id2
               , id3
               , custId) c
    on a.id = c.id
      and a.id2 = c.id2
      and a.id3 = c.id3
      and a.custId = c.custId
where (a.option1 = 'solo' or a.option2 = 0)
  and a.type = 'foo'
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0579/3).

So it uses `count(*)` and a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `count(1)` and `OUTER APPLY` respectively. `OUTER APPLY` gets applied to every row outside the query; you can use it for functions, but it can help code be more concise, too, like in this case. Just personal preference for me making these choices.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. Could you explain what everything does? I know it checks if it gets a null result and puts 0 children on it, but what does count(1) do? I will mark it as answer, but if it's not too much to ask some documentation would be nice :) Thanks again.

Comment: also i'm assuming it should be `c.option1 is null` instead

Comment: Hi, @Nimchip, I've tried to document everything, but describing code is harder than writing it! Anyway, I'm glad the query works and I hope the extra detail is helpful. I also corrected a minor typo - whoops! Make sure you are basing your code on these latest versions.